# cannot send long path filename (UNC path) to printer

Tags: windows, command-line, printing, unc

i'm using long path names with UNC (UNI), for example:

```
\\?\c:\tmp......\file1.prn
```

but when i try to send the file to a printer on windows command-line, for example with copy/print command, it shows :
for copy -

> 0 files copied

for print -

> invalid switch

the regular path / shortened (using ~) works well, its only the UNC large (>260 chars) that does not work.